# React.js How to filter data by month and push it to its respective month?

Tags: reactjs

I have my mock json data that each entry has `"id":1,"Date":"07/11/2021","Amount":74,"Category":"OnlineShopping"` etc.

What I want to do is take the entire list of data and filter out each month into its respective card so that each month has all of the data points with the same month.

I am currently checking if the year is same as the current year to leave out old data. What would be the best way from here to filter out the remaining data into the 12 months so each month will have a list of all the data points that match that month?

So if there are 20 data points that have a month value of 01, then the January block would get all those etc. for each month.

```
const expenses = MOCK_DATA.filter(i => i.Category !== 'Savings');
let sortedExpenses = expenses.sort((a, b) => new Date(...a.Date.split('/').reverse()) - new Date(...b.Date.split('/').reverse()));
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sortedExpenses));
const dates = data.filter((d) => d.Date.slice(-4) === new Date().getFullYear().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Loop through each item in the data array, slice off the month, find the same month in the monthsList array, and push it to the dataset for each one.

```
var monthsList = [
    {label: "Janurary", value: '01', dataset: []},
    {label: "February", value: '02', dataset: []},
    {label: "March", value: '03', dataset: []},
    {label: "April", value: '04', dataset: []},
    {label: "May", value: '05', dataset: []},
    {label: "June", value: '06', dataset: []},
    {label: "July", value: '07', dataset: []},
    {label: "August", value: '08', dataset: []},
    {label: "September", value: '09', dataset: []},
    {label: "October", value: '10', dataset: []},
    {label: "November", value: '11', dataset: []},
    {label: "December", value: '12', dataset: []},
]

dates.forEach(i => {
    var expense = i.Amount;
    var month = i.Date.slice(0, 2);
    monthsList.find(m => m.value === month);

    for (let j = 0; j < monthsList.length; j++) {
        if (monthsList[j].value === month) {
            monthsList[j].dataset.push(expense);
        }
    }
});
```